# prepend one div in body in .inc file

Tags: 7, javascript

I want prepend one div using `jQuery`, But the div has to be generated dynamically, so I can not add it in `html.tpl` file.

I have tried below code

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery("body").prepend("'+download_list()+'"); });', 'inline');


function download_list(){
    $output = "I am testing my div prepend";

    return $output;
}
```

But it is not working , whats the correct way to do this, please help

I am using `Drupal 7`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were using JS string concatenation syntax in PHP. Try

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery("body").prepend("' . download_list() . '"); });', 'inline');


function download_list(){
    $output = "I am testing my div prepend";

    return $output;
}
```